# Cómo detectar si se cambia manualmente de "Disabled" a "Enabled" un botón y no hacer la validación?

Tags: javascript, php

Encontré este pequeño [tutorial](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/simple-math-captcha-for-your-forms-with-php-and-javascript--cms-41653) para crear un captcha propio con PHP y JavaScript. Si la suma de 2 números es correcta, cambia de "disabled" a "enabled" un botón. El problema que encontré es que si quito manualmente el "disabled", la petición igual se hace. :/

¿Cómo podría verificar que si el botón se edita manualmente no se haga la petición? ¿O cuál es la mejor forma de solucionarlo?

PHP:

```
<?php
$min  = 1;
$max  = 300;
$num1 = rand( $min, $max );
$num2 = rand( $min, $max );
$sum  = $num1 + $num2;
?>
```

HTML:

```
<label for="quiz" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">
<?php echo $num1 . '+' . $num2; ?>?
    </label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input type="text" class="form-control quiz-control" id="quiz">
    </div>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <button id="botonAjax" data-res="<?php echo $sum; ?>" type="button" class="btn btn-dark w-100 fw-bold" disabled>Send</button>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
const submitButton = document.getElementById('botonAjax');
const quizInput = document.querySelector(".quiz-control");
quizInput.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
    const res = submitButton.getAttribute("data-res");
    if ( this.value == res ) {
        submitButton.removeAttribute("disabled");
    } else {
        submitButton.setAttribute("disabled", "");
    }
});
```

Comment: todo lo haces desde una misma pagina? porque para ese caso podrias usar solo javascript y validar si la suma de 2 numeros es correcta, no entiendo muy bien tu codigo, podrias explicarlo un poco mejor?

Comment: Este tipo de problemas es común del navegadar. El usuario mal intencionado puede modificar cualquier parte de la misma, incluso para aquellos con más conocimiento, se puede capturar la petición y modificarla para saltarse la validaciósn (incluso programaticamente). Esto lo resuelven en su mayoria los servicios como recaptcha. Pero para fines de estudio, en tu aplicación, yo te recomendaria hacer la validación en el backend, retornar una cookie con un valor perecedero solo para esa operación y al apretar el boton submit mandarla e eliminarla.

Comment: @ernestojimenez es correcto, tengo el php  hasta arriba de mi html. el código genera 2 números aleatorios que el usuario debe sumar, y si la suma es correcta, se habilita el botón principal

Comment: @Legna sé lo más básico de PHP y estoy igual en Javascript, no sé como hacerlo:(

Comment: Tentativamente puedes quitar el submit si la validación en el backen no es correcta.

Comment: si alguna de las respuestas en tus preguntas solucionan tus dudas, recuerda marcaslas como solucionadas.

Answer (score 0):

Normalmente lo manejaria con php y una session, por ejemplo:

Al cargar la pagina con el captcha crearias la variable:

```
$_SESSION['CC_TOKEN'] = false;
```

Entonces cuando el usuario valida la suma haria un evento que envie los datos y lo valide en el Backend PHP; si el captcha fue resuelto... como parte del analisis de ser todo correcto pasaria el valor de la session a true:

```
$_SESSION['CC_TOKEN'] = true;
```

Siguiendo con lo propuesto, habilitaria el boton; en este escenario si le da click al boton enviando nuevamente el otro evento ahora de submit; validaria que la variable de session sea `true`:

```
if(!$_SESSION['CC_TOKEN']){
    echo 'No se pudo validar el captcha Correctamente, vuelva a intentarlo!';
}
```

Que pasa si se edita el `html` para habilitar el boton y el captcha no se resolvio?

Pues entrara en el `if` siempre ... ya que la resolucion del captcha es lo que permite cambiar el valor del `$_SESSION['CC_TOKEN']`.

que hacer si se refresca la pagina, se debera programar el restablecimiento de la variable de sesion a false...

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que ese input estará debajo de algún formulario que será el que ejecute la acción. Siendo así lo que puedes hacer es usar el evento `submit` del formulario para también validar si el captcha es correcto antes de hacer la petición. y cambiar el que el botón sea tipo `submit` y no tipo `button`.

```js
const submitButton = document.getElementById('botonAjax');
const quizInput = document.querySelector(".quiz-control");

//Cree la funcino validateCaptcha para poder usarla tanto en el input como en el submit
function validateCaptcha(){
  const res = submitButton.getAttribute("data-res");
  return quizInput.value == res;
}

quizInput.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
    //Descomenta todo este código para que también bloquee el botón (tal cual como lo tienes en tu pregunta)
    //Yo lo tengo comentado para que puedas ver el comportamiento de lo que propongo en el submit
    /*
    if (validateCaptcha()) {
        submitButton.removeAttribute("disabled");
    } else {
        submitButton.setAttribute("disabled", "");
    }
    */
});

const myform = document.getElementById('myform');
myform.addEventListener("submit", function(e){
  if(!validateCaptcha()){
    console.log("El captcha no es valido, no se enviará el formulario");
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
  //Else, lo dejamos continuar con su accion por defecto que es enviar el formulario
  //En este caso pongo aqui un alert para que se vea que envia
  alert("enviando formulario");
});
```

```html
<form id="myform">
  <label for="quiz" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">
      2 + 5
      </label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
          <input type="text" class="form-control quiz-control" id="quiz">
      </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
      <button id="botonAjax" data-res="7" type="submit" class="btn btn-dark w-100 fw-bold" >Send</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Asi no importa si el botón está o no activo, el navegador no dejará de enviar el formulario.

> Si por alguna razón el botón no está dentro de un `form` y usas el evento `onClick` para realizar la acción, entonces ahí debes también hacer la validación antes de realizar la acción.

Comment: Se ve bastante bien, pero hay forma de que el botón no sea de tipo submit? Lo que pasa es que en mi formulario envío los datos por ajax Fetch sin refrescar la página. Si lo cambio a submit se refresca la página y eso es lo que no quiero:(

Comment: Como dije a lo ultimo, entonces puedes validar el captcha en el onClick del boton